# Trigger Lambda function by S3 PUT in subfolder of undefined folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function, that I want to trigger when a user uploads a file to a subfolder in their S3 directory.

Every user has its own folder inside the 'private/' prefix, but when the user is uploading a file, it's put in a subfolder. This means that the trigger prefix should be 'private/*userID*/subFolder/', but I can't find how to define that the userID could be anything.

I have tried making the prefix 'private/*/subFolder/', but that doesn't trigger anything. If I make the prefix 'private/', the function will be triggered unnecessarily.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a dynamic value for your trigger. So a solution is to get the event at a generic level like /prefix and then get the path of object. Extract the data you want and call your actual lambda. You can do this in 1 lambda as well and don't have to create 2.

```
S3 -> Lambda (extract path here) -> (actual) Lambda
```

Alternate solution is to add the message in SQS after parsing the path. And then call Any number of lambda's accordingly.

```
S3 -> Lambda (extract path here) -> Path1 -> SQS1 -> Lambda
```

OR

```
S3 -> Lambda (extract path here) -> SQS -> Lambda
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a rule for each user:

```
private/userID1/subFolder
private/userID2/subFolder
private/userID3/subFolder
```